# Raspberry PI MONO System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, mono

I am compiling a C# Console program using VS2015 and copying the executable over to a RPI B+.  I have installed Mono-Complete on the RPI. Everytime I execute the program, I receive the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
>   was thrown by the type initializer for UPBRaspberry.PortDataReceived
>   ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager:get_AppSettings (): method
>   body is empty.
>
> at UPBRaspberry.PortDataReceived..cctor () [0x00000] in :0   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
>   was thrown by the type initializer for UPBRaspberry.PortDataReceived
>   ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager:get_AppSettings (): method
>   body is empty.
>
> at UPBRaspberry.PortDataReceived..cctor () [0x00000] in :0   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I suspect the issue may have something to do with the following method:

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sp.ReadBufferSize];

    // There is no accurate method for checking how many bytes are read
    // unless you check the return from the Read method
    int bytesRead = sp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // For the example assume the data we are received is ASCII data.
    UPBString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance offered to resolve this issue.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="COMPORT" value="COM4" />
    <add key="UPSTARTEXPORTFILE" value="59wood~1.upe" />
    <add key="NETWORKID" value="01" />
    <add key="SOURCEID" value="FF" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: The error is about retrieval of settings - are you using settings in your app? [This post on github](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2710) indicates that you may have a malformed settings file.

Comment: Yep, I'm using app.config which I modified.  The modifications are listed in the original post at the bottom.  I can't see anything wrong with them

Comment: I temporarily solved the problem by removing the following state and hard coding the values                                                                             filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UPSTARTEXPORTFILE");